# Java myHandler S3 Put Client Timeout in Lambda

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Wondering if someone here has some insight. I can't figure out what may be blocking my lambda function from writing to s3, it seems to be timing out. I have given the role for the lambda full s3 access rights but it shouldn't be required because I pass credentials on the classpath.

This works locally when I run from a fat jar:

```
$ java -cp dronze-app-fat.jar com.dronze.aws.lambda.HelloAwsLambda 

trying to write to bucket.
{"result":"SUCCEED"}
```

But hangs in lambda.

```
START RequestId: 1dbeabac-eff1-11e5-a1ca-611b19003683 Version: $LATEST 
initializing s3Client.
trying to write to bucket.
END RequestId: 1dbeabac-eff1-11e5-a1ca-611b19003683 
REPORT RequestId: 1dbeabac-eff1-11e5-a1ca-611b19003683  Duration: 15002.75 ms   Billed Duration: 15000 ms Memory Size: 512 MB   Max Memory Used: 107 MB  
2016-03-22T05:44:45.228Z 1dbeabac-eff1-11e5-a1ca-611b19003683 Task timed out after 15.00 seconds    
Mar 22, 2016 3:46:24 PM com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient executeHelper 
INFO: Unable to execute HTTP request: connect timed out 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out 
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) 
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) 
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) 
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) 
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
```

The lambda method just writes an s3 json document:

```
private void saveToS3(String jsonDocument, String bucketName, String keyName, LambdaLogger logger) { 
    if(s3Client == null){
        logger.log("initializing s3Client.");

        ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration();
        config.setConnectionTimeout(14000);

        s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(
                new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider(
                "application-prod.properties"), config);

        s3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));
    }

    try {
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                jsonDocument.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String bucket = bucketName;
        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentType("application/json");
        metadata.setContentDisposition("attachment; filename=\"" + keyName);
        metadata.setContentLength(jsonDocument.length());

        PutObjectRequest put = new PutObjectRequest(bucket, keyName,
                stream, metadata);
        put.setStorageClass(StorageClass.ReducedRedundancy);
        put.setMetadata(metadata);

        logger.log("trying to write to bucket.");
        s3Client.putObject(put);

    } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
        logger.log("Caught an AmazonServiceException, which "
                + "means your request made it "
                + "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response"
                + " for some reason.");
        logger.log("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
        logger.log("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
        logger.log("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
        logger.log("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
        logger.log("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
    } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
        logger.log("Caught an AmazonClientException, which "
                + "means the client encountered "
                + "an internal error while trying to "
                + "communicate with S3, "
                + "such as not being able to access the network.");
        logger.log("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The behaviour seems to be something related to the role of the lambda function, or a security group being able to connect to s3 (I didn't think lambda have security groups) but something is blocking the s3 client put even though the role allows it:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DetachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::dronze.lambda.b283/*"
      }
    ]
}
```

I have bumped up memory and timeouts to bizarre levels and it still is blocked. This seems to be a networking issue not resources. Any insight on a solution is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you give your Lambda function VPC access?

Comment: I am facing similar issue. VPC access is provided to the Lambda function. any help please @MarkB

Comment: @DecKno you will have to add a NAT gateway to your VPC